# Using 'ref' as array in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ref

I have some issues when im trying to reference inputs as arrays in React with Redux.

The code below maps one Panel per article in the array.

```
var articles = this.props.item.array.articles.map((article, index) => {
     return <Panel key={index} header={'Article ' + index}>
        <Input type='select' ref='id' label='Article' defaultValue={article.id} >
          {articles}
        </Input>
     </Panel>
})
```

I'm trying to construct the refs so that they're in an array format, which does not seem to be possible at the moment. [Array of references. #1899](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1899)

I guess i could solve this by create some sort of `ref="article["+counter+"][id]"`

But that is a horrible solution, and i really don't want to go down that path.

The json array below would be my desired format for the refs:

```
"articles": [
        {
            "_joinData": {
                "price": "100",
                "quantity": "50"
            },
            "id": "05f54207-fb6f-40b5-820e-26059a803343"
        },
        {
            "_joinData": {
                "price": "200",
                "quantity": "70"
            },
            "id": "05f54207-fb6f-40b5-820e-26059a803343"
        }
]
```

The price & quantity index would be 2 more inputs.

Which i've decided to not include in the code example.

A nice solution to this problem would be very appreciated.

Comment: The question is not clear. `this.refs` is a `String`-keyed `Object`, not a "JSON array"

Comment: No it's not and what i meant was that my desired output for the articles index would be a json array in the specified format.

Comment: How is that array related to `refs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can iterate through `this.refs` like an array by using `Object.keys`.

Ex. `Object.keys(this.refs).forEach(key => func(this.refs[key]))`

To run `func` function for each reference.

Comment: this can be simple: Object.values(this.refs)