# Scroll to element in an array after rendering using React ref callback

Tags: reactjs, callback, ref

I would like to use ref callback to scroll to an element in an array after rendering.
Depending on state, it will scroll to different element based on `this.state.scrollToId`.
But I think the callback in the below code was not triggered before `componentDidUpdate`

P.S. `Item` is a customised component.

I have tried `componentDidMount` too.

- Researches done:
- [Using 'ref' as array in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35317082/using-ref-as-array-in-react)
- https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs
- [How to assign refs to multiple components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055464/how-to-assign-refs-to-multiple-components)

```
class A extends React.Component{
//... 
    state = { scrollToId: null}
    scrollToMyRef = (myRef) =>{
        window.scrollTo(0, myRef.current.offsetTop)
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.itemRefs = {};
        this.setItemRef = (element, id) => {
            this.itemRefs[id] = element;
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        if (this.state.scrollToId){
                scrollToMyRef(this.itemRefs[this.state.scrollToId])
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.state.aList.map((item)=>{
                        return (
                                <Item ref={(element) => {this. setItemRef(element, item.id)}}
                                </Item>
                        )

                    })
                }
            </div>)
     }
}
```

- Expected: based on the state, the page would scrolled to the corresponding element
- Actual: `itemRef[id]` was undefined, and throw exception on `scrollToMyRef`

Comment: I don't see `this.setSlotCardRef` define anywhere. Maybe `this.setSlotCardRef` is `this.setItemRef` ?

Comment: sorry, copied by mistake, should be `setItemRef`